# Java control print output format

Tags: java, format

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] names = {"Regina Kareem Obrien","Gretchen Brewer","Marty Cox","Roxie Blankenship","Stacey Trujillo","Ahmad James","Jordan Sykes","Frankie Hodge","Marguerite Doyle","Wilmer Baldwin"};
        String[] address = {"Avenida Ressano Garcia","Rua Roberto Duarte Silva","Avenida de Roma","Rua da Betesga","Rua Damasceno Monteiro","Rua de São Julião","Rua de São Mamede","Rua do Comércio","Rua do Salitre","Rua dos Bacalhoeiros"};
        String[]  dob = {"1999/8/26","2008/5/24","2002/10/7","2010/1/26","2005/11/21","2007/4/9","1999/8/26","2008/5/24","2002/10/7","2010/1/26"};
        int[] phone = {607544367,604903566,411315929,261809725,538236027,442128744,117255969,241273904,666757780,316948768};

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println("Name: " + names[i] + " Address: " + address[i] + " DOB: " + dob[i] + " Phone: " + phone[i]);
        }
    }
```

this prints like this:

```
Name: Regina Kareem Obrien Address: Avenida Ressano Garcia DOB: 1999/8/26 Phone: 607544367
Name: Gretchen Brewer Address: Rua Roberto Duarte Silva DOB: 2008/5/24 Phone: 604903566
Name: Marty Cox Address: Avenida de Roma DOB: 2002/10/7 Phone: 411315929
Name: Roxie Blankenship Address: Rua da Betesga DOB: 2010/1/26 Phone: 261809725
Name: Stacey Trujillo Address: Rua Damasceno Monteiro DOB: 2005/11/21 Phone: 538236027
Name: Ahmad James Address: Rua de São Julião DOB: 2007/4/9 Phone: 442128744
Name: Jordan Sykes Address: Rua de São Mamede DOB: 1999/8/26 Phone: 117255969
Name: Frankie Hodge Address: Rua do Comércio DOB: 2008/5/24 Phone: 241273904
Name: Marguerite Doyle Address: Rua do Salitre DOB: 2002/10/7 Phone: 666757780
Name: Wilmer Baldwin Address: Rua dos Bacalhoeiros DOB: 2010/1/26 Phone: 316948768
```

Is it possible to format the way the output its formatted?

I would like something like this:

```
Name: Regina Kareem Obrien   Address: Avenida Ressano Garcia       DOB: 1999/8/26  Phone: 607544367
Name: Gretchen Brewer        Address: Rua Roberto Duarte Silva     DOB: 2008/5/24  Phone: 604903566
Name: Marty Cox              Address: Avenida de Roma              DOB: 2002/10/7  Phone: 411315929
Name: Roxie Blankenship      Address: Rua da Betesga               DOB: 2010/1/26  Phone: 261809725
Name: Stacey Trujillo        Address: Rua Damasceno Monteiro       DOB: 2005/11/21 Phone: 538236027
Name: Ahmad James            Address: Rua de São Julião            DOB: 2007/4/9   Phone: 442128744
Name: Jordan Sykes           Address: Rua de São Mamede            DOB: 1999/8/26  Phone: 117255969
Name: Frankie Hodge          Address: Rua do Comércio              DOB: 2008/5/24  Phone: 241273904
Name: Marguerite Doyle       Address: Rua do Salitre               DOB: 2002/10/7  Phone: 666757780
Name: Wilmer Baldwin         Address: Rua dos Bacalhoeiros         DOB: 2010/1/26  Phone: 316948768
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soln to your issue:

```
System.out.println(String.format("Name: %-20s Address: %-30s DOB: %-10s Phone: %s",
                names[i], address[i], dob[i], phone[i]));
```

use - for right padding with spaces

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.out.format(...)`. For example:

```
System.out.format("%10s%15s%20s", s1, s2, s3)
```

will pad `s1` string to 10, `s2` String to 15 and `s3` string to 20 characters.

Take a look at [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) javadoc. It explains this topic thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks. Will look in to Formatter

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [`System.out.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf), which uses a [format string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to specify and format it's output.

You can use a width specifier with the `%s` argument to produce the right formatting, such as: `%-30s`. The `-` is important, it'll left align the text. eg.

```
System.out.printf("Name: %-30s, Address: %-30s...", names[i], address[i]);
```

Have a play around with it to get it the way you like.

Comment: Great. Will play aroud for a while. It's one more way

Answer (score 1):

i guess `\t` should help you.
try to play around with this tag, let's say like this:
`System.out.println("Name: " + names[i] + "\t Address: " + address[i] + "\t DOB: " + dob[i] + "\t Phone: " + phone[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use tabs, or look at `JCurses` for formatting console output.

Comment: JCurses is very handy when building commandline/terminal applications.